# TS2364: Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

`a` is a mutable array, so why can't I assign to it?

#### foo.ts

```typescript
export let a: any[];
```

#### bar.ts

```typescript
import {a} from './foo';

a = [5,6,7];
```

Answer (score 4):

`a` contains a mutable array, so you can mutate it:

```
a.splice(0, a.length, 5, 6, 7);
console.log(a);
```

`a` in `bar` is an imported binding however, and those cannot be reassigned. That's why it's a syntax error.

You can assign to `a` in `foo` however, where it's just behaving like a normal variable.

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined", checking the generated JS for foo.ts it was empty, only had a `"use strict";` line

Comment: @AT: Ah, sorry, I was confused by that typescript notation. You'll have to do `export let a: any[] = […];` of course to actually export an array.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to change the value of the array inside the original scope (`foo.ts`) then you can do something like:

```
export var a = {
    arr: []
}
```

and then in `bar.ts`:

```
import {a} from './foo';

a.arr = [5,6,7];
```

Comment: In fact that would also work with `const`. I was using an object before which is why I wasn't getting this error...

Comment: Yeah, a `const` will work as well as you don't change the reference just what's in it.